# Attachment wont come over from site.com

Tags: apex, attachment, site.com

I am trying to have an external site for our clients to be able to submit cases to our team. I have the VF set in place to have them submit a case and allow them to be able to add an attachment for a screenshot or more documentation. When they submit the record with an attachment the record is created (as expected) but it doesn't look like the attachment comes over at all. I feel like it is not reading the myAttachment.Name but the file that I insert has a name hence the it being able to be saved.

Am I taking the wrong approach to this?

VF:

```
        <apex:page Standardcontroller="Case" extensions="attachController" showheader="false" >
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{!$Resource.siteLogo}" />
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/now-ui-kit/2e8e665f/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
        <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/now-ui-kit/2e8e665f/assets/css/now-ui-kit.min.css?v1.2.0" media="screen"/>
        <title>Submit a Case</title>
        <style>

            p, li, .description{
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.8rem;
            }

            .paddingTop{padding-top: 2rem;}
            }

            .background-black{background: #2196f3;}

            .background-black:hover, 
            .background-black:focus{background: #2386d3 !important;}      

            section .section-inner h2{color: #fff;}

            .round {
            border-radius: 100px;
            margin: 0;
            color: #9a9a9a
            }

            .longBox{height: 100px;}


            @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
            .brand .h1-seo{
            font-size: 2.2rem;
            }

            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <apex:form styleclass="form-signin"><br/><br/><br/>
                <br/><h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create a Ticket</h2><br/><br/>
                <h5 class="form-signin-heading">Email</h5><br/>
                <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Email__c}" required="true"/>
                <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Subject</h5><br/>
                <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Subject}" required="true"/>
                <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">What are you experiencing?</h5><br/>
                <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.What_are_you_experiencing__c}" required="true"/>
                <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Where is the location of your issue?</h5><br/>
                <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Location_of_issue__c}" required="true"/>
                <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Source Type</h5><br/>
                <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Source_Type__c}" required="true"/>
                <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Description</h5><br/>
                <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control longBox" value="{!case.Description}" required="true"/><br/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg background-black btn-round round"/><br/>
                <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg background-black btn-round round " action="{!submit}">Submit</button><br/><br/><br/> -->
                <apex:pageBlock >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                        <div id="upload" class="upload">  
                            <h6>
                                If you have more than 1 file to upload please zip file to include all files. 
                            </h6>
                            <apex:inputFile title="Choose File" value="{!filebody}" filename="{!filename}" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg background-black btn-round round"/>                            
                        </div>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
    public class attachController
{
public case objcase{get;set;}
public Attachment myAttachment{get;set;}
public string fileName{get;set;}
public Blob fileBody{get;set;}

public attachController(Apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
{
    objcase = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    myAttachment = new Attachment();
}
public PageReference submit(){
    if (fileName != null){
        objcase.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Product Case').getRecordTypeId();
        insert objcase;
    } else {
        objcase.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Product Case').getRecordTypeId();
        insert objcase;
        System.debug('@@@@@fileBody'+fileBody);    
        myAttachment = new Attachment();
        Integer i=0;
        myAttachment .clear();
        myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
        myAttachment.Name = fileName ;
        myAttachment.ParentId = objcase.id;            
        insert myAttachment;   
    }             
    pagereference pr = Page.thankYouForSubmittingYourProductCase;                          
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Do not put a form inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379610). It will not work the way you expect. Instead, put a div around your `apex:form` and apply any classes you like there. It should have the same effect.

---

Update: Also, you're checking myAttachment.Name for null, but it will always be null, because you have not yet assigned the value from fileName to it. Check fileName first:

```
if(fileName == null) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
```

Comment: I updated the vf on my original post. I got rid of the extra form and it saved but when I tried to test it the record was never created.

Comment: @JoshuaAnderson you are checking the wrong variable. See updated answer.

Comment: Looks like everything is now working. I updated the submission so that it can be referenced and I appreciate it. If I wanted to move this to files instead of to the Notes & Attachments. Is that something that I would do like

public File myAttachment{get;set;}

or would I have to do that a different way?

Comment: @JoshuaAnderson It's more complicated than that. You'll want to look at ContentDocument, which has several related items as well.